# How many unique titles?

Tags: mysql

I need to count how many records there are where the `title` field has unique values.

I can select those records by:

`SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY title`

But when I tried to count them. I get the number of duplicates. Not the number of rows.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY title`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Can you make it clear that you don't simply want `distinct` but precisely "how many records there are without duplicate title fields" ?

Comment: In MS SQL, you can do `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Title) FROM table`. Not sure about MySql, though

Comment: @dystroy distinct provides the functionality the OP is requesting. I'm pretty sure they can judge from the manual that they would also do a `count()` or something, since distinct only says it acts as a filter. We can give the OP a little credit.

Comment: @dystroy what's the difference? In the set ("abc","abc","def","ghy") I would expect the unique count to be 3 (not 4).

Comment: @JoelDavis If you read exactly what is written, the count would be zero if all records were duplicated.

Comment: @JoelDavis I wish I could -1 your comment. Please don't recommend `w3schools`

Comment: @dystroy ah, ok now I see what you're saying. I think a lot of people are doing the same thing I did. He's only looking for unique values.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO At least there are no deep seated emotional issues backing that comment.

Comment: @JoelDavis lol, I can't count how many times I've been b!tch slapped for linking to w3schools.

Comment: @JoelDavis Huh? Have you been to [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com)?

Comment: The query in the selected answer returns the number of distinct values, which is a significantly different result than the number of rows that have a unique value.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO my point is that you apparently had a very visceral reaction to me posting a page despite the fact that actually did contain information most thought was what the OP was needing. If the page was incorrect OK, but having an emotional reaction to a domain name probably indicates there's more going on there.

Comment: The title of the question has been modified. This question now seems to be conflating the ideas of "distinct" and "unique", which are two very different things. The property of being "unique" means that no other rows share the same value, that there are no duplicates, while "COUNT(DISTINCT" implies that we do not care if the values are actually "unique" or not.

Comment: @JoelDavis SO hates W3. There are many users here that would have the exact same reaction when seeing links to W3. It's nothing personal. They react that way if anyone posts to that site.

Comment: @JoelDavis [here's a more rich discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource)

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Yeah I'm not taking it personally, the tone would've gone downhill incredibly fast instead of resulting in me telling a joke if that were the case. It's just a little too knee-jerk to just see a particular domain name and go straight to calling a person out on it. This is actually more conversation about ithan I thought was going to happen when I made my first response.

Comment: @JoelDavis I think SO runs a secret scripts to monitor all threads for outbound links to W3. Cause if you post a link it only takes a few seconds before someone says something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT title) FROM table;
```

Comment: Well, not if you OP really wants what he asks for, that is "how many records there are without duplicate title fields".

Comment: Hmmm? What do you mean @dystroy ?

Comment: This seems to work. It returns a smaller value which would be correct.

Comment: @Neal Well, given OP comments it seems he didn't really want to know how many titles were without duplicates. Too bad, this would have been an interesting question.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini You are welcome :-D

Comment: @dystroy it seems like he _did_ want what my answer says.

Comment: oh sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: This returns a number of distinct values for title, which is something very different than "the number of records without duplicate `title` fields". Consider a table where a title occurs in two or more rows, and consider that happens for every title. The number of records without a "duplicate" title would be zero.

Answer (score 2):

To get a count of the number of rows that have a value for `title` that does not appear in any other row:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS count_of_rows_without_duplicate_title
  FROM ( 
         SELECT `title`
           FROM `table`
          GROUP BY `title`
         HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
       )
```

The question asked by the OP was to get "a count of records without duplicate value". The "trick" here is to include a predicate on the aggregate, in a HAVING clause. For values of title that occur in only one row (no duplicate value in any other row), the COUNT(1) will be exactly one.

This result is SIGNIFICANTLY different than queries in other answers, which get a count of the number of distinct values for title. These are really two different questions.

Consider:

```
title
------
apple
banana
banana
orange
orange
orange
```

The distinct number of title values is three, BUT the number of rows that are "without duplicate value" of title is one.

Comment: +1 . . . You seem to answer the question, even though the question is not what the OP really wants answered.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I added the answer for the benefit of future readers, who may be looking for an answer to the actual question that was asked. The query in the "selected answer" returns a "smaller number" (according to a comment by the OP), and so it meets his needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY title)
```

Alternatively you could use the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: Please don't use `GROUP BY` this way.